# React: Passing props to parent returns <empy string>

Tags: reactjs, state, parent

First let me put my code here and I'll explain what's happening.

Parent.js

```
callback = (id) => {
    this.setState({des: id});
    console.log(this.state.des);
}

//on my render i have this when i call my child component
<Child callback={this.callback}/>
```

Child.js

```
handleChange = (event) => { 
    let des = event.target.value;
    console.log(des);
    this.props.callback(des);
};
```

When i `console.log`on my Child component, it returns the data that i want to pass, but when I do it in `calback`on my Parent component, it returns `<empty string>` and i don't know why that's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because setState is an async function. When you are trying to log this.state.des, the state would not have been set yet.  If you want to console log your state to see if it has been set as expected, what you want to do is log it in the callback of this.setState (so it logs once we know state is set).  Try something like the following in your parent.js :

```
callback = (id) => {
   this.setState({des: id}, () => {
       console.log(this.state.des); 
   });
}
```

see the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) for setState for more details

Answer (score 2):

The call to `setState` is asynchronous and therefore you might not read the updated state if you are accessing it directly after calling `setState`. Because of this `setState(updater[, callback])` actually exposes a callback which can be used for operations which depend on the state update being done. (This is explained in the [react docs for setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).)

In your case, adjusting the callback function like this

```js
callback = (id) => {
    this.setState({des: id}, () => {
        console.log(this.state.des);
    });
}
```

should do the trick.

If you want to know more about the reasoning behind `setState` being asynchronous (even if it might be a bit confusing in the beginning, like in your case) you should check out [this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11527) and especially [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11527#issuecomment-360199710).